# Any way to identify source of traffic on Amazon KDP?

Tags: amazon, ebook-management, sales, kdp

Given a kindle book published on Amazon KDP, is there a way to find out from where traffic or sales came from?

For example, I might add links pointing to my book on my website, or on social media, on forums or whatever and I want to know from where my readers came from, to optimize my strategy of recommending or advertising for the book on one channel or another. Obviously, from my own website I can see on what links people click and I can measure that interaction, but on other channels like forums or social media I have no control whatsoever, I can only add a link and somehow add some parameters to that link to later find out from KDP where users came from.

I could not find anything related to how one might do that. I found examples with parameters like:

```
https://www.amazon.com/.../?tag=12345
https://www.amazon.com/.../?channel=MyWebsite
https://www.amazon.com/.../?ref=BlaBla
```

But no information about what these parameters do, or if they are even valid, or if there is a KDP report that shows them.

The best I could find is the Amazon Associate program, where you can create an affiliate account, but I don't need that. It's my own book and I just want to know where buyers come from, it's not an affiliation.

Is there any way to find out this information?

Comment: Good question, I am curious. One option that comes to me is creating a short link, see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZ4Ggk66HlE&t=8s . With short link you can see statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Found the question interesting, but I do not have the answer. But here it goes a possible way.
You will need:

1. A link to your Amazon book;
2. A shortening app, I like to use this one: https://app.bitly.com/bbt2/

Here goes the link to my book: https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B09WPXSFMB

Just add something: https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B09WPXSFMB?test
See it still works just fine.

Now the magic: https://amzn.to/3jp8ujy
This is the shortened version from the one with parameter, after the question mark.

See the picture, just did one access! it works!

[image]